# Should I supply two non-isolated boost converters from the same 5V?

Tags: boost

I have two DC-DC boost converters:

- **5V -> 170V**

  - to power some Nixie tubes
  - normally draws 500 mA of current at 5V
  - non-isolated (because there is only one GND pin)
- **5V -> 400V**

  - to power a Geiger tube
  - normally draws 3 mA of current at 5V
  - non-isolated (I have checked that the input GND pin is short to the output GND pin)

**Is it a good idea to supply these two boost converters from the same 5V DC source?** (or should I say "5V rail" in the jargon? I am not sure what is meant by "rail", so avoid the jargon here) The 5V DC source is a wall-plugged transformer capable of supplying 2.5 A.

I have actually tried this.

1. At first everything seemed fine.
2. At some point (after 24 hours), Converter #2 (400V)'s output voltage started to drop significantly ...
3. I unplugged Converter #1 (170V) and Converter #2's output voltage resumed ...
4. I plugged in Converter #1 again, Converter #2's output voltage immediately dropped by 5V. (It's not unusual to see Converter #2's output voltage float up/down 5V, but the sudden-ness of this 5V drop seems to suggest Converter #1 interfering)

I also have tried to supply the 5V from a (cheap) benchtop power supply. In this case, Converter #1 worked OK, but Converter #2 stopped working at all (output voltage reached 90V at max). And I heard some buzz/ringing (whatever it's called).

So, I kind of suspect the answer to my question is "No". Can someone explain more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to _edit your question_.  A partial answer is that yes, **in principle** it should be fine to do what you're doing -- you've got a supply that should be good for 2.5A, and you're asking for a bit more than 0.5A from it.  _This should create no problem_.  Thus, the problem is in the rest of the circuit, and you need to tell us more: what converters are you using?  What is the voltage on your 5V supplies each time a problem crops up?  If possible, post an oscilloscope trace of your 5V supply.  If possible, post what the current into the 170V supply is when things go wrong.

Comment: Could you provide a schematic and what converters are you using?

Comment: You should "separate and decouple" the "power supply" of the two converters.